# iOS Enterprise App with direct Socket / Push Messaging (AWS SNS?) in Background Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, background, websocket, amazon-sns

We're building an iOS Enterprise Distribution App (no App Store approval required) that will receive regular data updates from a server which are then relayed to a paired BLE device.

We started off using APNS with Silent Push Messages (using the content-available flag) but found that over periods of extended use iOS started throttling our app and not waking it to process the push messages when in the background.

When the app was in the foreground or plugged into mains power it was fine.

So we're looking at the Enterprise Distribution Path at the moment (its for a controlled environment)

The question is, does anybody have any suggestions on how we can keep this app Open/Running in the background to receive a stream of data?

I've seen plenty of articles about people using a Sound File on loop, or imitating a VOIP app to do this but they don't seem ideal due to impact on battery life and user experience (with the glowing VOIP status bar).

We've been using AWS SNS for the push messaging which is really good. From what i've read SNS also has a direct connection option that bypasses APNS which is exactly what we are after but can this still work when the App is in the background?

Are there any other ways via Enterprise Distribution that we can use to keep the app processing in the background?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm seeing similar issues.